# Sending nested request to node.js web server

Tags: node.js

I am about to teach creating a simple web server in node.js to my students. I am doing it initially using the http module and returning a static page. The server code looks like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    getFile(response);
}).listen(8080);

function getFile(response) {
    var fileName = __dirname + "/public/index.html";
    fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, contents) {
        if (!err) {
            response.end(contents);
        } else {
            response.end();
            console.log("ERROR ERROR ERROR");
        }
    });
}
```

index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Static Page</title>
    </head>
    </body>
        <h1>Returned static page</h1>
        <p>This is the content returned from node as the default file</p>
        <img src="./images/portablePhone.png" />
    </body>
</html>
```

As I would expect, I am getting the index.html page display without the image (because I am not handling the mime-type). This is fine; what is confusing me is, when I look at the network traffic, I would expect to have the index.html returned three times (the initial request, the image request and one for favicon.ico request). This should happen, because the only thing the web server should ever return is the index.html page in the current folder. I logged the __dirname and fileName var and they came out correctly on each request and there were indeed three requests.

So my question is, what am I missing? Why am I not seeing three index.html response objects in the network monitor on Chrome? I know one of the students will ask and I'd like to have the right answer for him.

Comment: The image isn't working because your web server doesn't have a route defined to handle the request for `./images/protablePhone.png`.  Remember a node.js web server serves NO files by default.  If you want your web server to server that image when requested by the browser, you have to have code that specifically serves that image.  In fact, your web server is serving the same `index.html` for ALL requested paths, no matter what path was requested.  So, when that image is requested, you will send the browser index.html which obviously won't work for your image.

Comment: I copied your code and I get 3 index.html responses (as expected). If you inspect each response you can clearly see they are all index.html. Maybe if you try to refresh or disable the filter? [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/2ptPs71.png)

Comment: Thank you, I know that. My question is why the response object in the image request has no data (I mistakenly thought favicon too, but both it and the localhost (initial) request have the index contents in the response object. So why don't I see that in the response object in Chrome for the image?

By the way, what you're not seeing are the next three examples where we get in to error handling, mime types, logging, etc. They will get there.

Answer (score 0):

> what is confusing me is, when I look at the network traffic, I would
>   expect to have the index.html returned three times (the initial
>   request, the image request and one for favicon.ico request)

When I run your app, I see exactly three network requests in the network tab in the Chrome debugger, exactly as you proposed and exactly as the HTML page and the web server are coded to do.  One for the initial page request, one for the image and one for favicon.ico.

The image doesn't work because you don't actually serve an image (you are serving index.html for all requests) - but perhaps you already know that.

> So my question is, what am I missing? Why am I not seeing three
>   index.html response objects in the network monitor on Chrome?

Here's my screenshot from the network tab of the Chrome debugger when I run your app:

[image]

Comment: I get the same thing; however, my question is why the response object in the portablePhone.png request is not index.html. When I select the image file and look under the response tab it says there is no preview available. For both the initial request (localhost) and favicon.ico it is the index.html page. Why is the image behaving differently?

Comment: @A.McDonald - Funny that that is now what you say you're asking because your actual question does not ask that.  It's probably because the request for the image has these headers: `Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8` and since index.html isn't one of those types, nothing is sent or whatever is sent is ignored by the browser because it's the wrong type.

Comment: @A.McDonald - When the browser requests an image, it knows it's requesting an image.  It's not going to process a response that is not an image.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Just for clarity, my original question was, "Why am I not seeing three index.html response objects in the network monitor on Chrome?" Not sure how it could have been clearer.

Comment: @A.McDonald - Well, I posted a screen shot that showed three response objects in the Chrome network tab after requesting `index.html` 3 times.  I didn't know you were looking for something specifically in those response objects that you weren't seeing.  That part of what you meant to ask was not obvious to me (or apparently to the other person who wrote an answer).  Anyway, I think you've got your explanation now - I was just surprised to finally understand what you actually were trying to ask.  No problems now.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you actually wrote (originally, can't be sure you won't edit the question) just serves an `index.html`.  There is nothing in there that could read any other file (like an image).

I don't think you should teach students that syntax/mechanism because it is outdated.     For starters, do not teach them to indent with tabs or four spaces.  Indent with 2 spaces for JavaScript.  Also, it just doesn't make sense to teach ES5 at this point.  They should learn ES2015 or later (ES6/ECMAScript 2016/whatever they call it).  For the current version of Node out of the box (6.6 as of writing), this would be the equivalent of what you wrote:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs-promise');

http.createServer( (request, response) => {
  fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/public/index.html`)
  .then( data => {response.end(data)} )
  .catch(console.error);
}).listen(8080);
```

But what you seem to be trying to do is create a gallery script.

Another thing about Node is, there are more than 300,000 modules available.  So it just absolutely does not make sense to start from 0 and ignore all 300,000+ modules.

Also, within about three months, 6 at the most, `async/await` will land in Node 7 without requiring `babel`.  And people will argue that kids will be confused if they don't have enough time toiling with promises, but I don't think I buy that.  I think you should just teach them how to set up `babel` and use `async/await`.  Overall its going to make more sense and they will learn a much clearer way to do things.  And then the next time you teach the class you won't need `babel` probably.

So this is one way I would make a simple gallery script that doesn't ignore all of the modules on `npm` and uses up-to-date syntax:

```
import {readFile} from 'fs-promise';
import listFilepaths from 'list-filepaths';
import Koa from 'koa';

const app = new Koa();

app.use(async (ctx) => {
  if (ctx.request.querystring.indexOf('.jpg')>0) {
    const fname = ctx.request.querystring.split('=')[1];
    ctx.body = await readFile(`images/${fname}`);
  } else {
    let images = await listFilepaths('./images',{relative:true});
    images = images.map(i=>i.replace('images/',''));
    ctx.body = `${images.map(i=> `<img src = "/?i=${i}" />` )}`;
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am interested in why I am getting the response I am and not getting into a debate over versions and modules. That is a conversation best had in another forum. I know about the thousands of modules in node and about ES6, but that is not where these students are at presently.

Comment: I'm curious where you get that indentation of 2 spaces per level is standard for Javascript.  Can you cite a reference for that?  I personally find it much, much harder to line up indent levels at only 2 spaces and code that has highly nested indentation needs to be simplified anyway so 4 spaces is never a problem in my code.  What is your reference citation for saying that 2 spaces is the standard for Javascript?

Comment: Yes, and I am aware of what I am serving and doing it on purpose. My question is why the response object on the image request does not contain the index.html contents. The response object on the other two requests (I thought only the original request, but favicon request has it too) contains the contents of index.html, but the png object does not.